# jquery greybox conflict with parent page?

Tags: jquery, textfield, greybox

every one i am having a problem in greybox when the box/popup appears,there are text fields from the parent page still visible and i can type in them.please give/share any suggestions or idea. Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    GB_showCenter('Claim Application form',url,500,600,closeBack);

                if(document.getElementById('txtEmployeeId'))
                {
                        document.getElementById('txtEmployeeId').style.display='none';
                }
                document.getElementById('txtExpenseTitle').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('txtFwdEmployeeId').style.display='none';


function closeBack(){
            document.getElementById('txtExpenseTitle').style.display='';
            document.getElementById('txtFwdEmployeeId').style.display='';
            if(document.getElementById('txtEmployeeId'))
            {
                document.getElementById('txtEmployeeId').style.display='';
            }
       }
```

**It was very simple,hope it may help someone.**
may be my question was not proper or people did not liked it